# Calculating forest cover in given area/radius using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Just getting started with GEE and trying to achieve something fairly simple using the Hansen et al. dataset.

Basically, I have a series of GPS points, and I want to count the amount (pref %) forest cover remaining around each point - at different distances (e.g., 500m, 1km, 3km).

If I understand this correctly, there are several critical steps:

1. Masking out the loss pixels, to create an updated forest cover layer;
2. Count and convert the number of pixels in my buffer around each gps.

I have done this crudely using the following script, however, the values I am getting out look rather odd. I am wondering how much of this is just due to the raster/datalayer, or simply due to some obvious errors in my script.

```js
// Import Global Forest Change dataset.
var hansen_2020 = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2020_v1_8");

// Subset Global Forest Change the dataset.
var treeLoss = hansen_2020.select('loss');
var treeGain = hansen_2020.select('gain');
var treeCover = hansen_2020.select('treecover2000');
var treeCoverUpdated = treeCover.mask(treeLoss);
var greater10 = treeCoverUpdated.gte(10);
var treeCover_greater10 = treeCover.updateMask(greater10);

// Load GPS coordinates
var GPS = ee.FeatureCollection('users/MSc_project/GPSCords_allv2');

// Set 500m, 1km and 3km buffers
var GPS_500m = GPS.map(function (feature) {
  return feature.buffer(500, 1)
})
Map.addLayer(GPS_500m);

var GPS_1000m = GPS.map(function (feature) {
  return feature.buffer(1000, 1)
})
Map.addLayer(GPS_1000m);

var GPS_3000m = GPS.map(function (feature) {
  return feature.buffer(3000, 1)
})
Map.addLayer(GPS_3000m);

// Calculate forest cover
var forestImage = treeCover_greater10.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

// Count the forest cover pixels in 500m.
var forest = forestImage.reduceRegions({
  collection: GPS_500m,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  scale: 1
});

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: forest,
  description: '500m_forest_cover'});
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are getting odd values because you are multiplying the tree cover values (`treeCover_greater10`, values between 10 and 100) by the pixel area (`ee.Image.pixelArea()`). You might want to multiply `greater10`  (values of 0 and 1) by `ee.Image.pixelArea()` in order to obtain the area of pixels with more than 10 % of tree cover. Try defining `forestImage` like this:

```
var forestImage = greater10.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot.